# List AddRange from a specific index?

Tags: c#, list, addition

Is there an inbuilt function in the generic List to add a range from another list in a from a specific index or do I have to write my own?.

For example:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

list1.Add(10);
list1.Add(20);
list1.Add(30);

list2.Add(100);
//list2.AddRange(list1, 1) Add from list1 from the index 1 till the end
```

In this example, the list2 should have 3 elements: 100, 20 and 30.

Should I write my own or is there an inbuilt function that can do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Shyju He's already aware of `AddRange()`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in-built to AddRange, but you could use LINQ:

```
list2.Add(100);
list2.AddRange(list1.Skip(1));
```

Here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/RRxkUZ).

Answer (score 5):

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

list1.Add(10);
list1.Add(20);
list1.Add(30);

list2.Add(100);
list2.InsertRange(1,list1.Skip(1));
```

***Output on Printing:***

100

20

30

You can use InsertRange combined with a linq skip method, which will skip the first element. If you want to insert after a specific index.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `List<T>.InsertRange(Int32, IEnumerable<T>) Method` that inserts the elements of a collection into the List at the specified index. Where `Int32` is the zero-based index at which the new elements should be inserted and `IEnumerable<T>` the collection whose elements should be inserted into the List. .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insertrange?view=net-7.0

In your example:

```
list2.InsertRage(1, list1)
```